# How to generate date in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this urgent question about date in php. I want to query the database for certain records before a certain date, say I want records within 30 days, so first thing is I get current date, and I want to calculate the other end of the date range, how can I do that? Do I need to do this in mysql query or in php? Much appreciated!

Comment: That depends on whether you store dates in your DB as unix timestamp or as mysql DATE(TIME) type

Comment: Yes, I store date type field in mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do that in mysql.

eg.

```
SELECT * from myTable where date_column > date_sub(now(), interval 30 day);
```

now()  or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  -> will give you a value of current date.
`date_sub`, and `date_add` are functions used to add or subtract interval
from given date.

Documentation here :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: @Michael: be aware that this query does not get cached very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can Generate the Current Date in PHP like this:

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d"); // the output will be in the format YYYY-MM-DD
echo $current_date;
```

You can learn more about PHP dates and Date formats here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

You can also select certain rows from a DB Table using WEEK() and MONTH() . I asked a question related to it yesterday : [MySQL: Select data from a table where the date falls in the current Week and current Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705050/mysql-select-data-from-a-table-where-the-date-falls-in-the-current-week-and-curr)

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally considered better practice to construct the intervals in php than use MySQL's built-in functions (such as `NOW()`). There's a very good reason for that.

Suppose you use a query using `NOW()` (`SELECT t.foo, t.bar FROM table t WHERE created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 30 day);`). The function returns a date with an accuracy down to the last second (e.g `'2006-04-12 13:47:36'`). Caching this query is quite useless as it is worthwhile for only this 1-second period.

Most applications hardly require this level of accuracy and generally an accuracy of 1 day is good enough. You can already see that constructing a query with less accuracy is a lot more beneficial as the result is cached the first time and any subsequent queries will hit the cache for a whole day.

Here is an example in PHP

```
$pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);

$sql = 'SELECT t.foo, t.bar FROM table t WHERE t.created_at >= ?';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')));
$stmt->execute();
```

For more information about PDO, take a look at the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)