# Mysql Query for events over the last 14 days (fortnightly)

Tags: mysql, scheduling

I'm writting some scheduling code that checks for events that occuried `Daily`, `Weekly`, **`Fortnightly`** and `Monthly`.

So far I've worked out how to do `Daily`, `Weekly`, `Monthly` but not **`Fortnightly`**. 
My table structure is...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event_log` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `export_schedule` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `import_schedule` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `exception` TEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

**Resources**

- [[RESOLVED] Select records fortnightly](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10354763-RESOLVED-Select-records-fortnightly)
- [MYSQL DATETIME Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
- [MySQL: Select data from a table where the date falls in the current Week and current Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705050/mysql-select-data-from-a-table-where-the-date-falls-in-the-current-week-and-cur)

Say for instance the current date is `11-1-2012` (1st of November) and the last event occured on `10-20-2012` (20th October 2012) *13 days ago* if I was to query that event, MySQL would return with `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0004 sec)`. With my current query.

`SELECT * FROM event_log WHERE MOD(DATEDIFF(date,CURDATE()),14)=0` *(Events from the current bi-week)* but it doesn't get me the any results.

How can I query for events that occured within the last fortnight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`SELECT * FROM event_log WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)`

If you ensure there is an index on the date column, this query will allow that index to be used to keep things fast as well.